# Converting json array to xml using XSLT

Tags: json, xml, xslt

i have a front end page that send a request to an data service deployed to wso2 console for doing an update in a table.
The problem is that i need to convert the json array from the front end to an xml format for build the payload factory for the request.
The json is :

```
{"cdcList":
["UpdateCdc":
    {
 "idCdc":1,
     "order":1,
     "cdcName":"test 1",
    },
 "UpdateCdc":
    {
     "idCdc":2,
 "order":2,
     "cdcName":"test 2",
     "idParent":1
    },
  "UpdateCdc":
    {
     "idCdc":3,
     "order":1,
     "cdcName":"test 3",
     "idParent":1
     }
]
```

}

and the desired result in xml that i would like that it will be is :

```
<cdcList>
          <UpdateCdc>
        <idCdc>1</idCdc>
        <order>1</order>
            <cdcName>test 1</cdcName>
          </UpdateCdc>
          <UpdateCdc>
            <idCdc>2</idCdc>
            <order>2</order>
            <cdcName>test 2</cdcName>
            <idParent>1</idParent>
          </UpdateCdc>
          <UpdateCdc>
            <idCdc>3</idCdc>
            <order>3</order>
            <cdcName>test 3</cdcName>
            <idParent>1</idParent>
          </UpdateCdc>
</cdcList>
```

Thank you.

Comment: XSLT is for XML transforms, not json.  What programming language, as there are plenty of libraries to convert json to xml

Comment: XSLT 3.0 has a "json-to-xml" function. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590058/convert-json-to-xml-using-xslt-3-0-functions

Comment: I don't think the input you have shown is even JSON, https://jsonlint.com/ says "Error: Parse error on line 2" , "Expecting 'EOF', '}', ',', ']', got ':'" for the colon in `...cList": ["UpdateCdc": { ` after the `UpdateCdc`.

Answer (score 2):

To do client-side processing in XSLT with support for JSON parsing you will need an XSLT 3.0 processor, which in practice means Saxon-JS. (Disclaimer: that's my company's product.)

Unfortunately the input you supplied isn't valid JSON, but let's assume it is actually like this:

```
[
    {
        "idCdc": 1,
        "order": 1,
        "cdcName": "test 1"
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 2,
        "order": 2,
        "cdcName": "test 2",
        "idParent": 1
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 3,
        "order": 1,
        "cdcName": "test 3",
        "idParent": 1
    }
]
```

Then you can convert it to your desired XML format using the following XSLT 3.0 code:

```
<xsl:variable name="json-array" select="json-doc('input.json')"/>
<cdcList>
  <xsl:for-each select="$json-array?*">
    <updateCdc>
      <xsl:for-each select="map:keys(.)">
         <xsl:element name="{.}">
           <xsl:value-of select="map:get(.)"/>
         </xsl:element>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </updateCdc>
  </xsl:for-each>
</cdcList>
```

Answer (score 2):

While Michael Kay's answer gives you XML (see it online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cf/) I think it has one shortcoming, the order of the keys of an XPath 3.1 map is not defined so with `map:keys` you might get any order for the child elements (e.g. in the linked example it is `idParent`, `idCdc`, `cdcName`, `order`) while you probably want to define the order for the child elements based on the order in the JSON. That can be achieved using the `json-to-xml` function already mentioned by Tim in a comment:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions"
    xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/math"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    xmlns:array="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/array"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs math map array fn"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:param name="json-input" as="xs:string">[
    {
        "idCdc": 1,
        "order": 1,
        "cdcName": "test 1"
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 2,
        "order": 2,
        "cdcName": "test 2",
        "idParent": 1
    },
    {
        "idCdc": 3,
        "order": 1,
        "cdcName": "test 3",
        "idParent": 1
    }
]</xsl:param>

  <xsl:variable name="json-array" select="parse-json($json-input)"/>

  <xsl:variable name="json-xml" select="json-to-xml($json-input)"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <cdcList>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$json-xml/*"/>
    </cdcList>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:map">
      <updateCdc>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </updateCdc>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fn:map/fn:*">
      <xsl:element name="{@key}">
          <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cf/2 has that example, in https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFDb2Cf/1 I also output the result of the `json-to-xml` call so that you can see how the JSON input is mapped to XML:

```
<array xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <map>
      <number key="idCdc">1</number>
      <number key="order">1</number>
      <string key="cdcName">test 1</string>
   </map>
   <map>
      <number key="idCdc">2</number>
      <number key="order">2</number>
      <string key="cdcName">test 2</string>
      <number key="idParent">1</number>
   </map>
   <map>
      <number key="idCdc">3</number>
      <number key="order">1</number>
      <string key="cdcName">test 3</string>
      <number key="idParent">1</number>
   </map>
</array>
```